# Reading from file, tokenizing, sorting using compareTo() doesn't work?

Tags: java, collections, tokenize

I am reading data from text file, tokenizing using split(), using it to populate a Student Object, saving it in a list and sorting it.(if names are same, sort as per age. if age is also same, sort as per rollno).

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {try{
        Scanner scr=new Scanner(new File("studentdetails"));
        String str1=scr.nextLine();

        String[] tokens1=str1.split(",");
        Student s1 = new Student(Integer.parseInt(tokens1[0]), tokens1[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens1[2]));

        String str2=scr.nextLine();
        String[] tokens2=str2.split(",");
        Student s2 = new Student(Integer.parseInt(tokens2[0]), tokens2[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens2[2]));

        String str3=scr.nextLine();
        String[] tokens3=str3.split(",");
        Student s3 = new Student(Integer.parseInt(tokens3[0]), tokens3[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens3[2]));

        List<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(s1);   list.add(s2);   list.add(s3);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

and here is my Student class which implements the comparable interface.

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private int rollno;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    Student(int r, String n, int a){ rollno=r; name=n; age=a;}

    public String toString()
    {return rollno+" "+name+" "+age;}

    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        if(name != s.name)  return (name).compareTo(s.name);
        if(age != s.age)    return new Integer(age).compareTo(s.age);
                            return new Integer(rollno).compareTo(s.rollno);
        }
}
```

Contents of studentdetails are as follows :(first column is rollno, third is age)

```
33,Zack,44
5,Anna,5
4,Zack,4
```

Now the funny thing is, My data gets sorted as per the name, but if names are same, it doesn't sort as per age , rollno etc.

The compareTo() works if I manually populate the list. However reading from file, tokenizing and sorting gives error.

Spent an entire day debugging.All you JAVA mavens out there, can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You're deciding if names are "equal" using their identity (`==`, `!=`) rather than their value (`equals()`).

`name` and `s.name` are not the same object when read in from a file, even if they have the same value. Your comparator should be checking their value instead. You didn't notice this before, because the compiler will intern the literal strings in your sources, so if you write the same string twice *in source code*, it will be the same object, and `==` and `!=` will appear to work.

Your comparator should look more like this:

```
// first compare by name. If different, return that immediately.
final int nameDiff = name.compareTo(s.name);
if (nameDiff != 0) return nameDiff;

// name is the same. Now compare age and return if different.
final int ageDiff = age - s.age;
if (ageDiff != 0) return ageDiff;

// final layer of sorting: rollno
return rollno - s.rollno;
```

Comment: Usually compareTo returns 0, -1, or 1 based on the comparison. This isn't crucial, but it is a bit strange when a student named "A" gets -1 when compared to "B", but if there are two "B" students with an age gap of 10 years, you get -10, which kindof implies one of the "B" students should come before "A".

Comment: Chill, please take a look at the [formal definition of `Comparator.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29). It only ever gives the relative position between two items. Note that it's carefully defined that `sgn(compare(A,B)) == -sgn(compare(B,A))`, not that `compare(A,B) == -compare(B,A)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally use this kind of code for this situation.

```
      public MyClass{
            private String names[];
            private int ages[];
            private int roll[];

            public void TextFileReader(){
            Scanner ob = null;
            try{
            ob = new Scanner(new FileReader("studentdetails"));
            int c = 0;
            while(ob.hasNext()){`
            String sp = ob.next();
            String arr[] = s.split("\\;");
            roll[c] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            name[c] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            age[c] = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
            c++;
}
            }
    catch(FileNotFoundExcpetion e){
    System.out.println("Error"+e.getMessage);
    }
            }


            public void sort(){
            for(int i = 0; i < names.lenght; i++){
                for(int c = i + 1; c < names.length; c++){
                 if(names[i].CompareTo(names[c]) > 0){
                    roll[i] = roll[i] + roll[c];
                    roll[c] = roll[i] - roll[c];
                    roll[i] = roll[i] - roll[c];
                    age[i] = age[i] + age[c];
                    age[c] = age[i] - age[c];
                    age[c] = age[i] - age[c];
                    String n = names[i];
                    names[i] = names[c];
                    names[c] = n;
    break;
    }
    if(age[i] > age[c] && name[i].compare(names[c]) == 0){
     roll[i] = roll[i] + roll[c];
                    roll[c] = roll[i] - roll[c];
                    roll[i] = roll[i] - roll[c];
                    age[i] = age[i] + age[c];
                    age[c] = age[i] - age[c];
                    age[c] = age[i] - age[c];
                    String n = names[i];
                    names[i] = names[c];
                    names[c] = n;
    break;
    }
    if(roll[i] > roll[c] && age[i] = age[c] && names[i].CompareTo(names[c]) == 0){
     roll[i] = roll[i] + roll[c];
                    roll[c] = roll[i] - roll[c];
                    roll[i] = roll[i] - roll[c];
                    age[i] = age[i] + age[c];
                    age[c] = age[i] - age[c];
                    age[c] = age[i] - age[c];
                    String n = names[i];
                    names[i] = names[c];
                    names[c] = n;

    }

        }
        }
        }


        public String[] getNames(){
        return names;
        }

        public int[] getRoll(){
        return roll;
        }

        public int[] getAge(){
        return age;
        }

        public int getCount(){
        return c;
        }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    MyClass ob = new MyClass();
    ob.TextFileReader();
    ob.sort();
    int count = ob.getCount();
    String x[] = ob.getNames();
    int y[] = ob.getAge();
    int z[] = ob.getRoll();
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
    System.out.println(z[i]+","+x[i]+","+y[i]);
    }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### This will never compare on anything but name:

Properly formatted you can see your problem:

This compares name and returns, it will never ever evaluate `age` or `rollno`.

```
public int compareTo(Student s) 
{
    if(name != s.name) 
    {
        return (name).compareTo(s.name);
    }
    if(age != s.age)
    {
        return new Integer(age).compareTo(s.age);
    }
    return new Integer(rollno).compareTo(s.rollno);
}
```

#### Idiomatic Solution:

This may look overly complex for this particular case, but this simple case is a great example of how to build something that will use the appropriate interfaces to be as modular as possible.

Using `Comparator` instead of putting all the logic directly in the `Comparable` gives you more flexibility in the order that things are compared in.

This is a straw man solution, as I never use `Comparable` unless it compares every field for equality and not multi-field sorting like this.

A `CompositeComparable` would have the code that `compareTo` has in this example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CompositeComparable
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Student s1 = new Student(33, "Zack", 44);
        final Student s2 = new Student(5, "Anna", 5);
        final Student s3 = new Student(4, "Zack", 4);

        final List<Student> l = new ArrayList<Student>();
        l.add(s1);
        l.add(s2);
        l.add(s3);
        Collections.sort(l);
        for (final Student s : l)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static class Student implements Comparable<Student>
    {
        private int rollno;
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public Student(int r, String n, int a)
        {
            rollno = r;
            name = n;
            age = a;
        }

        public String toString(){ return String.format("%d,%s,%d", rollno, name, age); }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(final Student o)
        {
            int result = new NameComparator().compare(this, o);
            if ( result != 0 ) { return result; }
            result = new AgeComparator().compare(this, o);
            if (result != 0) { return result; }
            result = new RollComparator().compare(this, o);
            if (result != 0) { return result; }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class NameComparator implements Comparator<Student>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Student o1, final Student o2)
        {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
    }

    public static class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Student>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Student o1, final Student o2)
        {
            return Integer.compare(o1.age, o2.age);
        }
    }

    public static class RollComparator implements Comparator<Student>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Student o1, final Student o2)
        {
            return Integer.compare(o1.rollno, o2.rollno);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
5,Anna,5
4,Zack,4
33,Zack,44
```

#### Bonus Code:

Here is a generic `CompositeComparator`.

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CompositeComparator <T> implements Comparator<T>
{
    private List<Comparator<T>> comparators;

    public CompositeComparator(@Nonnull final Comparator<T>...comparators)
    {
        this.comparators = new ArrayList<Comparator<T>>(Arrays.asList(comparators));
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(final T o1, final T o2)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (final Comparator<T> c : this.comparators)
        {
            result = c.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) { break; }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```